# Need to arrange several plots (3*2) in a single page (grid.arrange) (With Unified X axis) and shifted y axis

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying on faceting six plots in a single page using ggplot. in 3*2 grid.
and also changing the y label from left to right for all the plots in second column.
I am trying to have only one scale for all the 6 plots combined. 
How to have single x axis for 1st and second column of plots ?

I have a function like below...

```
plot_4 <- function( for (i in 1:7) { var[i] = readline("enter the variable name \n")\n) {
# var [i] doesnt work, how to get multiple inputs in this case ?
#Next I am doing aggregation, and its fine
gg4 <- aggregate(cbind(get(var1),get(var2),get(var3),get(var4),get(var5),get(var6))~Ei+Mi+hours,a, FUN=mean)
#For future calling purpose I am using below vector to store the variable names
myvars<-c(var1,var2,var3,var4,var5,var6)
names(gg4)[4] <- var1
names(gg4)[5] <- var2
names(gg4)[6] <- var3
names(gg4)[7] <- var4
names(gg4)[8] <- var5
names(gg4)[9] <- var6

# Plotting for each variable 
plot_exp <- function(i,plotvar) {  
  dat <- subset(gg4, var = myvars[i] ) # myvars [i] doesnt work, I dont know how to choose each #variable separately for each iterations here in R.
    ggplot(gg4,aes_string(x="hours", y=eval(get(var)), fill = "Mi")) + 
    geom_point(aes(color= "Mi"), size = 3) + 
    geom_smooth(stat= "smooth" , alpha = I(0.01), method="loess", color = "blue") +
    facet_grid(myvars~.)
}
#Arranging in grid
ll <- do.call(Map, c(plot_exp, expand.grid(i=1:6, plotvar=myvars, stringsAsFactors=F)))
do.call(grid.arrange,  ll)
}
```

This is not working.
Please help to fix the error in above code and also few changes as I described in beginning.

I have did little arrangements to get the graph into what I wanted (Except the Y axis on right, but its ok), But now I am not able to edit the legend title.

```
ggplot(dd,aes(x=hours, y=value)) + 
  geom_point(aes(color=factor(Mi)), size = 4, alpha = I (0.5))  +
  geom_smooth(stat= "smooth" , alpha = I(0.01), method="loess", color = "blue") +
  facet_wrap(~variable, nrow=3, ncol=2,scales = "free_y")
```

Legend is like
![enter image description here][2]
 How can I edit the legend name , I dont want to have factor(Mi) as its name. Please let me know.
Thanks in advance.

I have used `scale_fill_continuous(guide = guide_legend(title = "V"))` and `scale_fill_continuous(name = "V")`

But both doesnt work here.

Comment: perhaps it would be easier to melt the data and use `facet_grid`? I haven't really looked at the data. Could you just `dput` it and provide your read-in code used? I am horrendously lazy, and it is very much suggested that you provide a minimal, *self-contained* example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than looping and calling `ggplot` multiple times, it's better to melt your data into one data.frame and then plot all at the same time using facets to arrange your plots. This will automatically help coordinate the x-axes.

First, let's start at the point where you have `myvars`. For example

```
myvars <- c("Nphy", "Cphy", "CHLphy", "Nhet", "Chet", "Ndet")
```

Now we can extract those values from `gg4` and "melt" them so that each observation is on it's own row.

```
dd <- melt(gg4,id.vars=c("Ei","Mi","hours"), measure.vars=myvars)
```

Now we can make all the plots at once with

```
ggplot(dd,aes(x=hours, y=value, fill = Mi)) + 
    geom_point(aes(color=Mi), size = 3) + 
    geom_smooth(stat= "smooth" , alpha = I(0.01), method="loess", color = "blue") +
    facet_wrap(~variable, nrow=3, ncol=2)
```

And that's it!

[image]

Comment: Thanks that works 100%. and is it possible to have Y axes for 2nd column plots on the right side (Keeping the first column plots as it is) ? (its just feasible for the observer, and also different plots have different scales). I did not find any function here. So please help if you have an idea..thanks.

Comment: The ggplot author does not like axes on the right or top so has decided not to implement that feature. You can search the web for workarounds if you like.

Comment: In that case how can we have Y-axis for individual plots. I mean each plot with its own Y axis ? in the above scenario ?

Comment: @statisticalbeginner You can do `scales="free_y"` to give each plot their own independent y-axis so each range will be different. But if the ranges are coordinated via `facet_wrap` there is no easy option to repeat the same axis for both columns that i'm aware of.

Comment: Yeah scales = "free_y" does works fine. Now I have to find out a way to tilt the column 2 plots 180 degree to bring y axis on right side. Thanks again.

Comment: Just one last question, As you know i am grouping based on Mi value and Mi = c[1:9] and the legend for this is shown in blue and there is no clear distinguish between the colors. I have added the pic of it, please let me know how to get the scaling from 1 to 9 in integer values and also the different color for different values.

Comment: @statisticalbeginner right now `Mi` is a numeric vector. Just change it to a factor in the data.frame. That will give you discrete colors rather than a continuous scale.

Comment: Yeah I found that, but as I posted the name is like factor(Mi) how can I edit it ? I have used few commands as I posted, and both of them not working. (cant we change the legend title if plotted using facet?). Please let me know.

Comment: @statisticalbeginner This is really a different question unrelated to the original post. It's not a food idea to edit questions to ask something complete different. It's better to start a new question.